# Reading from and writing to multiple ip's with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been through a tutorial with Node.js, but it seems everything was aimed at what to do with it from the server side.  I was playing around with it to see how it would work writing to multiple devices on our network with non-blocking i/o.  Here's what I have so far (rough code, sorry):

```
var net = require('net');

var nodes = [<list of IP addresses>];

function connectToServer(ip) {
        conn = net.createConnection(3083, ip);
         console.log ("Creating connection to: " + ip + "\n");
        conn.on('connect', function() {
                conn.write ("act-user::myuser:ex1::mypass;");
        });
        conn.on('data', function(data) {
                var read = data.toString();
                if (read.match('ex1'))
                {
                        console.log(ip + ": " + read);
                }
        });
        conn.on('end', function() {
        });
}

nodes.forEach(function(node) {
        connectToServer(node);
});
```

I see it go through the list and kicking off a connection to each IP address, but then it seems to write the login line to the same host over and over again.  I think somewhere I'm getting my streams crossed (just like Egon said to never do), but I'm not sure how to fix it.  The non-blocking node.js world is still kind of difficult for me to think through.

Comment: Put a `var` keyword in front of `conn = net.createConnection(3083, ip);`. You're re-assigning a single `conn` variable instead of having one per connection.

Comment: You should accept @gluxon's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is a JavaScript kink. In JavaScript, if a variable is defined without `var` before it, it will be set as global. This is happening to the `conn` variable in your `connectToServer()` function. `conn` is being overwritten and is not reset after the `connectToServer` scope is exited.

Try adding var in front of the following.

```
conn = net.createConnection(3083, ip);
```

Result

```
var conn = net.createConnection(3083, ip);
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.  I knew it was something simple.